# how to set bvalidator for struts conrol

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, struts2, validation

I have using struts framework to develop web application, in that web application , I am using Bvalidator for validation. when I using Bvalidator in the simple HTML, it's working fine, but when I use the same validator on Struts or Server control functions, it won't work. how can I do this on struts. kindly some one suggest some idea for this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly is this bvalidator?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi http://code.google.com/p/bvalidator/ It's a jQuery plug-in for client side form validation

Comment: @Pigueiras: Thanks :) i was confused with bean validator